# Ist der Satz "Geraucht werden darf." korrekt?

Tags: passive

Da das Deutsche nicht verlangt, dass die Subjektposition mit einem Expletivum sichtbar gemacht werden muss - Bedeutet das, dass ich sowohl `Es darf geraucht werden` als auch `Geraucht werden darf` sagen kann?

Comment: Ja, beides ist ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ja, das ist richtig und wird in bestimmten Kontexten tatsächlich benutzt, wenn der Satz mit dem sinntragenden Partizip beginnen soll.

> Lautes Abspielen von Musik und Singen sind hier nicht erlaubt. Geraucht werden darf aber.

> Speisen und Getränke können an der Theke gekauft werden. Nicht verzehrt werden dürfen mitgebrachte Speisen.